# PHP regex to extract two words

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to get the numeric values from a string. Ideally an array containing both numbers.

I am using this PHP but it only seems to match the first one and not the second.

```
$str = 'The address has changed from #1216640 to #1218908';

    preg_match_all(
    '/The address has changed from #(.+?) to #(.+?)/s',
    $str,
    $output,
    PREG_SET_ORDER
    );

print_r($output);
```

What I would like is an array that returns 1216640 and 1218908

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following, just search for the numbers followed by `#` in the string.

```
$string = 'The address has changed from #1216640 to #1218908';
preg_match_all('/#([0-9]+)/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1216640
    [1] => 1218908
)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the reg ex you are looking for

```
/The address has changed from #([0-9]+) to #([0-9]+)/s
```

See the screenshot below:
[image]